# Is there an easy way to edit enviroment variables in windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

I wish to be able to edit my environment variables in a more user friendly manner than the `Start Menu >My Computer>(right click)Properties>Advanced(tab)>Environment Variables`

... and then get those tiny unmanageable dialogs

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, not with the built-in commands in Windows.

[**Take Command Console LE**](http://www.jpsoft.com/tccledes.htm), a command interpretor compatible with cmd.exe, can save variables as System and User variables. Check the SET command with the /S and /U parameters respectively.

```
set /s sysvariable=whatever
set /u uservariable=whatever
```

I've not used it but [**Rapid Environment Editor**](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) looks good and is free.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `SET` doesn't change the variables permenantly - you want to use `SetX`.

> SETX [/S system [/U [domain]user [/P [password]]]] var value [/M]

Answer (score 0):

[Path Editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/)

[image]

Comment: Seems nice but it only takes care of the path variable, doesn't it?

Comment: @Yaneeve:yes....

Answer (score 0):

Use the commandline window (cmd) using the `SET` command...but pay attention using this way.
My prefered way is to copy out the variable value to any texteditor (like notepad) and modify the value there, copying back the new value afterwards. This tiny dialog is a pain since too long...